# inject html markup around random words in string using c#

Tags: html, c#, string

i want to inject html markup around random words in string like

"this is a string for this question"
the result should be like
"this is a string <"legend title="xyz">for<"/legend> this question".
i want to do it using c#
quotes are inserted to make markup appear

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://serverfault.com/questions/209291/inject-html-markup-around-random-words-in-string-using-c). And please **do** link your accounts.

Comment: Are you processing an HTML string you got elsewhere, or are you wanting to do this in ASP.NET code?

Answer (score 0):

Without actually coding it for you, I would suggest:

Count how many times a space appears in the string.

```
int NumberOfSpaces = 0;
foreach(char c in myString) {
    if(char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) {
    NumberOfSpaces++;
}
```

Then find a random number between 1 and that number.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.Next(1,NumberOfSpaces);
```

Do it however many times you want. Maybe once for every 10 spaces, of course, random.